# Sails.js - How do I reuse (most) of this code across multiple controller actions?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I'm grabbing feeds using a particular npm module and what I want to do is create multiple actions with the same code although I don't want to repeat the whole code. Here's my controller:

```
module.exports = {

    buzzy: function (req, res) {
        var FeedParser = require('feedparser'),
            request = require('request');

        var req = request('http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Technology.xml'),
            feedparser = new FeedParser();

        req.on('error', function (error) {
            // handle any request errors
        });
        req.on('response', function (res) {
            var stream = this;

            if (res.statusCode != 200) return this.emit('error', new Error('Bad status code'));

            stream.pipe(feedparser);
        });


        feedparser.on('error', function (error) {
            // always handle errors
        });
        feedparser.on('readable', function () {
            // This is where the action is!
            var stream = this,
                meta = this.meta // **NOTE** the "meta" is always available in the context of the feedparser instance
                ,
                item;

            while (item = stream.read()) {
                var newData = item;                        
                   Buzzfeed.create({'title': newData.title, 'url': newData.link, 'source': 'nytimesTech', 'category': 'tech'}, function (err, newTitles) {
                        });                       

            }
        });

    }
};
```

so similar to the 'buzzy' controller action, I want to create multiple actions - following are the lines that are going to be unique in each controller

```
var req = request('http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Technology.xml'),
```

and

```
Buzzfeed.create({'title': newData.title, 'url': newData.link, 'source': 'nytimesTech', 'category': 'tech'}, function (err, newTitles) {
                            });
```

Curious, what would be the best approach to implement this so I'm not repeating?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Services. If you have functions that are being used at multiple places in the code, you can use them.

See the documentation here: [Services](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Services)

Answer (score 3):

In the `/api/services` folder, create a file, name it `BuzzyAPI.js` (say), and add the following code:

```
var FeedParser = require('feedparser'),
request = require('request');

module.exports = {

  buzzy: function (reqUrl) {

    var req = request(reqUrl),
    feedparser = new FeedParser();

    req.on('error', function (error) {

    });
    req.on('response', function (res) {
      var stream = this;
      if (res.statusCode != 200) return this.emit('error', new Error('Bad status code'));
      stream.pipe(feedparser);
    });
    feedparser.on('error', function (error) {

    });
    feedparser.on('readable', function () {
      var stream = this,
      meta = this.meta,
      item;
      while (item = stream.read()) {
        var newData = item;                        
        Buzzfeed.create({'title': newData.title, 'url': newData.link, 'source': 'nytimesTech', 'category': 'tech'}, function (err, newTitles) {

        });
      }
    });    
  }
};
```

Now you can call the `Service` from any `controller` and provide the required `URL` using:

```
BuzzyAPI.buzzy(url);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks :-) this solved it, so essentially by creating a service controller as an object with one object having a function with parameters and then passing appropriate arguments in the controller actions did it :D

Comment: If this solves the problem, then please consider resolving this question by accepting this answer :)